# Action Script 3.0 error: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3

Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at MethodInfo-10(). I am getting this error while running this code. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong. It is not showing me where  the error is nor the line of the error. Thanks

```
package 
{
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Main()
        {
            stop();
            start_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gothere);
            function gothere(clickInfo:MouseEvent)
            {
                start_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gothere);
                nextFrame();
            }

            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, key_pressed);
            function key_pressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void
            {
                switch (event.keyCode)
                {
                    case Keyboard.UP :
                        {
                            player.y +=  -5;
                            if ((wall1.hitTestPoint(player.x - player.width/2, player.y - player.height/2,true)) || (wall2.hitTestPoint(player.x - player.width/2, player.y - player.height/2,true)))
                            {
                                player.y +=  5;
                                nextFrame();
                                playagain_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goback);
                                function goback(event:MouseEvent):void
                                {
                                    playagain_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goback);
                                    prevFrame();
                                }


                            }
                            else if ((wall1.hitTestPoint(player.x + player.width/2, player.y - player.height/2,true)) || (wall2.hitTestPoint(player.x + player.width/2, player.y - player.height/2,true)))
                            {
                                player.y +=  5;
                                nextFrame();
                                playagain_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goback1);
                                function goback1(event:MouseEvent):void
                                {
                                    playagain_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goback1);
                                    prevFrame();
                                }
                            }
                            else if (player.hitTestObject(finish))
                            {
                                gotoAndStop(4);
                            }
                            break;





                        };
                    case Keyboard.DOWN :
                        {
                            player.y +=  5;
                            if ((wall1.hitTestPoint(player.x - player.width/2, player.y + player.height/2,true)) || (wall2.hitTestPoint(player.x - player.width/2, player.y + player.height/2,true)))
                            {
                                player.y +=  -5;
                                nextFrame();
                                playagain_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goback2);
                                function goback2(event:MouseEvent):void
                                {
                                    playagain_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goback2);
                                    prevFrame();
                                }
                            }
                            else if ((wall1.hitTestPoint(player.x + player.width/2, player.y + player.height/2,true)) || (wall2.hitTestPoint(player.x + player.width/2, player.y + player.height/2,true)))
                            {
                                player.y +=  -5;
                                nextFrame();
                                playagain_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goback3);
                                function goback3(event:MouseEvent):void
                                {
                                    playagain_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goback3);
                                    prevFrame();
                                }
                            }
                            else if (player.hitTestObject(finish))
                            {
                                gotoAndStop(4);
                            }
                            break;





                        };
                    case Keyboard.LEFT :
                        {
                            player.x +=  -5;
                            if ((wall1.hitTestPoint(player.x - player.width/2, player.y - player.height/2,true)) || (wall2.hitTestPoint(player.x - player.width/2, player.y - player.height/2,true)))
                            {
                                player.x +=  5;
                                nextFrame();
                                playagain_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goback4);
                                function goback4(event:MouseEvent):void
                                {
                                    playagain_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goback4);
                                    prevFrame();
                                }
                            }
                            else if ((wall1.hitTestPoint(player.x - player.width/2, player.y + player.height/2,true)) || (wall2.hitTestPoint(player.x - player.width/2, player.y + player.height/2,true)))
                            {
                                player.x +=  5;
                                nextFrame();
                                playagain_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goback5);
                                function goback5(event:MouseEvent):void
                                {
                                    playagain_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goback5);
                                    prevFrame();
                                }
                            }
                            else if (player.hitTestObject(finish))
                            {
                                gotoAndStop(4);
                            }
                            break;





                        };
                    case Keyboard.RIGHT :
                        {
                            player.x +=  5;
                            if ((wall1.hitTestPoint(player.x + player.width/2, player.y - player.height/2,true)) || (wall2.hitTestPoint(player.x + player.width/2, player.y - player.height/2,true)))
                            {
                                player.x +=  -5;
                                nextFrame();
                                playagain_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goback6);
                                function goback6(event:MouseEvent):void
                                {
                                    playagain_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goback6);
                                    prevFrame();
                                }
                            }
                            else if ((wall1.hitTestPoint(player.x + player.width/2, player.y + player.height/2,true)) || (wall2.hitTestPoint(player.x + player.width/2, player.y + player.height/2,true)))
                            {
                                player.x +=  -5;
                                nextFrame();
                                playagain_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goback7);
                                function goback7(event:MouseEvent):void
                                {
                                    playagain_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goback7);
                                    prevFrame();
                                }
                            }
                            else if (player.hitTestObject(finish))
                            {
                                gotoAndStop(4);
                            }
                            break;



                    }

                }


            }
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: There's no function MethodInfo-10() in your code. The error means you're trying to access fields of a null (empty, not initialized) object reference. File > Publish Settings > Permit Debugging to learn the exact line that produces the error.

Comment: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Function/Main/$construct/key_pressed(). This is the error after changing the settings.

Comment: Most likely error in bracketing nested functions. Move them all to the same level as `Main()` as @Organis suggests, AND keep them there EVERYWHERE in your project. This will surely enhance your debugging and expanding ability.

Answer (score 2):

Start with making your code not-so-horribly-overweight-with-duplicates. Also, functions defined inside functions defined inside functions? So wrong on so many levels.

```
package
{
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Main()
        {
            stop();
            start_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goThere);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKey);
        }

        private function goBack(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            playagain_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goBack);
            prevFrame();
        }

        private function goThere(clickInfo:MouseEvent):void
        {
            start_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gothere);
            nextFrame();

            stage.focus = stage;
        }

        private function testPlayer():Boolean
        {
            if (wall1.hitTestPoint(player.x - player.width/2, player.y - player.height/2,true) return true;
            if (wall2.hitTestPoint(player.x - player.width/2, player.y - player.height/2,true) return true;
            if (wall1.hitTestPoint(player.x + player.width/2, player.y - player.height/2,true) return true;
            if (wall2.hitTestPoint(player.x + player.width/2, player.y - player.height/2,true) return true;

            return false;
        }

        private function movePlayer(dx:Number, dy:Number):void
        {
            player.x += dx;
            player.y += dy;

            if (player.hitTestObject(finish))
            {
                gotoAndStop(4);
            }
            else if (testPlayer())
            {
                player.x -= dx;
                player.y -= dy;

                nextFrame();

                playagain_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goBack);
            }
        }

        private function onKey(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            switch (event.keyCode)
            {
                case Keyboard.UP:
                    movePlayer(0,-5);
                    break;

                case Keyboard.DOWN:
                    movePlayer(0,5);
                    break;

                case Keyboard.LEFT:
                    movePlayer(-5,0);
                    break;

                case Keyboard.RIGHT:
                    movePlayer(5,0);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I totally agree with you about the functions, but if i put that it is showing me this error. Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Main/movePlayer()
 at Main/onKey()
ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on Main/goBack(). Expected 0, got 1.

Comment: Yep. I forgot to put the event argument. You should've figured that on your own.

Comment: yes, that I did. Thank you @Organis. I have one question regarding the working. When I start the game and press the start button, all the keyboard events stop working and when I do mouse click on the screen, it starts working. Is there a way I can resolve that.

Comment: I added stage.focus = stage; to goThere() method, try it. The problem occurs (probably) because start_btn has the input focus at the moment yet after the nextFrame() that start_btn ceases to exist and keypresses go to nowhere.